# How configure an snmpv3 authentication with an AD user?

Tags: active-directory, snmp, snmpd

I want to do snmpv3 authentication with an active directory user instead of a local user?

The servers are Red Hat Enterprise 8.7 integrated with the AD and have access to different active directory groups. I would like the authentication to be done by a user present in the active directory.

Answer (score 0):

SNMP is a protocol defined without any restriction on where the user accounts are. However, the tools (such as NET-SNMP) you use (either manager side or agent side) are often not AD aware.

For example, NET-SNMP specifically requires users to be configured in `snmpd.conf`, and each users needs to have authentication/privacy modes and passphrases chosen. That's not compatible with an AD user who usually has a single password.

Therefore, I'd like to say you shouldn't attempt to mix the two.

References

- [NET-SNMP](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmpd.conf.html)

Comment: There's nothing to say you can't use a single password for both authentication and privacy

Comment: And? Hard code algorithms for authentication and privacy also? If that's really an answer, why not post yours?

Comment: I don't know enough about Active Directory, but I don't see why someone couldn't write an integration

Comment: @TallChuck It's an open arena that anyone can post their questions/answers. Things like "how can I write a million lines of code web site in just Notepad?" can be discussed, but people have their own judgement on whether thins are reasonable and to pursue or not.

Comment: right, and so it's not helpful to give an answer that shuts down all discussion. Your answer cites a single library, and then broadly concludes that someone "shouldn't attempt to mix" AD and SNMP. I disagree. Though I don't know really anything about using Active Directory, I know enough about SNMP to say that I think it could probably be done, though I agree that NET-SNMP is not the right tool for the job.

Comment: @TallChuck then I doubt how much experience you have in the SNMP field, because NET-SNMP is much more than "a single library" but de facto standard implementation. That's why all mainstream OS except Windows ship its packages for it as default. BTW, it is rather interesting to hear that by posting an answer I am "shutting down all discussion". I won't comment further, or you believe I kill the thread.

Comment: I suppose that from an IT perspective, there may not currently be tools available to integrate SNMP with AD (though I reject the claim that NET-SNMP is the de-facto standard -- every network hardware vendor that I know of ships with at least their own agent implementation). However, if you are developing code that uses SNMP, there's no reason you could not use Active Directory for credentials. The question isn't clear on whether that's the case, but I suspect it's not, in which case, yes, it does come down to what tools and libraries are readily available